# Background color for stringstyle in lstlisting

Tags: color, listings, tcolorbox

I'd like to make a `lstlisting` style definition, where strings are highlighted with a background color, to make them stand out more. I'm not even sure it's possible, but let me explain.

Here is an attempt with `\colorbox`, which might give you an idea of what I want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{mypython}{
  keywordstyle=\bfseries,
  captionpos=b,
  language=Python,
  keywordstyle=\bfseries,
  identifierstyle=\color{black},
  ndkeywordstyle=\color{darkgray}\bfseries,
  commentstyle=\color{gray}\ttfamily,
  stringstyle=\color{black}\ttfamily\colorbox{black!10},
  showstringspaces=false
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=mypython]
{'timezone': 7200, 'cod': 200, 'dt': 1561470780, 'base': 'stations',
  'weather': [{'id': 804, 'icon': '04d', 'main': 'Clouds',
               'description': 'overcast clouds'}],
  'sys': {'message': 0.0076, 'country': 'DK',  'sunrise': 1561429582,
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Here is example output when using the above style on some JSON:
[image: output with colorbox]

As can be seen, there are several problems with this approach:

- apostrophes are highlighted separately from the rest of the text
- white-space is some places highlighted in the beginning of lines, where the string isn't started yet
- the colorboxes are not equal in height
- additional spacing between words and apostrophes have been introduced

Is it possible to do fix the above problems? Perhaps using `tcolorbox` or something else than `\colorbox`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Updated.